# Hide two DIVs and toggle a third on click, then reverse

Tags: jquery, html, hide

On click, my function hides first two `DIV`s and toggle the third `DIV`. This is working. When I click again on the same link the function toggle back the third `DIV`, this is also working. But the two previously hidden `DIV`s now remain hidden while they should be visible.

```html
<div>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div> -->CSS style is hidden
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#three").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show(); --> this shows my click link

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $("#three").slideToggle().load('testpage.php');
                $("#one").hide();
                $("#two").hide();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this...

```
$("#one").hide();
$("#two").hide();
```

to this...

```
$("#one").toggle();
$("#two").toggle();
```

or this...

```
$("#one,#two").toggle();
```

or this...

```
$(this).siblings().toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Qkva/)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="one">hi</div>
    <div id="two">hello</div>
    <div id="three">again</div>
</div>
<a class="show_hide">Show / Hide</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#three").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $("#three").slideToggle().load('testpage.php');
                $("#one").slideToggle();
                $("#two").slideToggle();
    })
});
```

Comment: Please don't just provide a link to jsFiddle, add the code to the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#three").hide().load('testpage.php');

    $(".show_hide").show().click(function(){
        $("#one").toggle();
        $("#two").toggle();
        $("#three").slideToggle();
    })

});
```

What i've done:

1) Merged the functions on .show_hide into a chain.

2) Changed the `hide()` functions into `toggle()`

3) Moved your `load()` call out of the loop, to prevent in from binding every time.

Comment: That isn't a event handler `.load()`. It's an AJAX `.load()`.